# Is this a Good Ajax-security practice?

Tags: php, ajax, curl, xmlhttprequest, request

In modern URL patterning (path-style), I'll make three requests:

1. /hello - will be available to the end-user
2. /getdata - will be the ajax handler on the server-side, witch will be initiated by/from /hello
3. /getresults - will be unavailable either from direct or Ajax access, but it will be available and responses from this script will be available from a "local-server access", for instance accessing it with cURL defined in the /getdata, and sending some specific headers from the /getdata - to ensure the safetiy of access.

This is just a theory of mine, I know it's possible, but I'm just wondering what do you all think about this "ajax-security-approach", and do you think that this whould be a safer way to "hide" your other sub-requests, or whatever?

I still have not done this, but I have this on my plan list.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Who would be able to access `/getresults` in this case?

Comment: it will be accessed by the ajax request: /getdata, via cURL, etc..

Comment: but if it will be accessed by the Ajax request, you can't limit it to local server access, can you?

Comment: main purpose of the /getdata is to parse the initial Ajax request sent from the /hello, and within itself (/getdata), shall execute this request /getresults (via cURL or other)... hope this clearifies :)

Comment: @Pekka, you don't get the idea right! both /hello and /getdata can be accessed from the outside world, wether from the Ajax or a regular Web request... the /getresults can be only accessed with specific HTTP headers send to it, and then it throws a response, and again that response is catched by the /getdata, and thrown back as an Ajax response, and then catched and previewed/executed to the end-user in the /hello!

Comment: But how would this add security? Seeing as anyone can forge the headers and make it look like it's a legitimate Ajax request?

Comment: It could! When the request /getresults is called from /getdata, you can throw some specific headers, POST; GET; data witch won't be sent from the AJAX request itself... if you know what I'm pointing on...!

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand the concept. Why make the detour if you're passing all the data through `/getdata` anyway? If your goal is to send data to the Ajax request, I don't see how this additional step adds security?

Comment: do you ever think about your Ajax request of making them unaccessable via direct access, meaning that only XmlHttpRequest request's could access them?

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> do you ever think about your Ajax request of making them unaccessable via direct access, meaning that only XmlHttpRequest request's could access them?

nope: it doesn't work that way. There is no way to make a resource available only to an Ajax request because any Ajax request is trivial to fake. All requests (including the Ajax one) will still originate from the client's IP, and you can never trust them.

If  `/getresults` contains sensitive data, it needs proper protection, e.g. through a login function.

Comment: you still don't get my idea what I'm trying to accomplish! I will make some working examples in a few days and you'll see what I'm trying to point out here!

Comment: all what you sad about requests, ajax, where from they originate is OK and true, .. but this is just another approach!

Comment: @Zlatan we seem to be misunderstanding each other. Yeah, it's probably best if you build some examples!